# Including run.bat and compile.bat in java project folder does what?

Tags: java, macos

As part of a college Java course project I've been asked to include a `compiler.bat` and a `run.bat` file in the projects root folder.

From attempts to get these to do anything, I can't get them to work on OSX 10.13 (High Sierra).

From reading Google, and SO results these seem to be windows relevant files only?

Am not sure about there relevance but they are a requirement of the project so I'd like to understand what's going on or required.

```
// compiler.bat ( 0775 Permissions )
@echo off
javac "./App.java"
pause  


// run.bat ( 0775 Permissions )
@echo off
java "./App"
pause
```

And both sit in the same directory, beside App.Java.

Comment: Open the *.bat files with a text editor and see what they contain. I think it should just be one line in each, where compile.bat compiles the *.java file in a *.class file and run.bat starts the file - but there is no way to know this if we don't know the contents of the files.

Comment: A fair point, I've edited the question.

Comment: You are right, `.bat` files are Windows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the `compiler.bat`, all it really does is call `javac`.
This is used to compile the `App.java` file, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).
It basically turns the written java code into a *.class file which contains the Java bytecode. This step is necessary for running any java program. There are a lot of explanations on the java bytecode available, for example [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077233/core-java/bytecode-basics.html).

`run.bat` is responsible for running the programm. It takes the compiled code and starts the program.

These to steps are necessary for running java programs, so they are for example also described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html)

Of course you don't need to use *.bat files for this. You can just as well use the same command from your command line:

```
javac "./App.java"
java "./App"
```